# Can't compile Oracle docs example

Tags: java

this is my first question here so bear with me please.

I'm trying to use the Oracle Java docs, but when I try to compile [example 6 on this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm) it doesn't work.  I've tried everything I can think of.  It's an old example, so that may be the issue, but it's disheartening that I can't figure out what should be a minor problem.

Example 6 Using an InvalidationListener

```
package bindingdemo;

import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.binding.NumberBinding;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;

class Bill {

    // Define the property
    private DoubleProperty amountDue = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    // Define a getter for the property's value
    public final double getAmountDue(){return amountDue.get();}

    // Define a setter for the property's value
    public final void setAmountDue(double value){amountDue.set(value);}

     // Define a getter for the property itself
    public DoubleProperty amountDueProperty() {return amountDue;}

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Bill bill1 = new Bill();
        Bill bill2 = new Bill();
        Bill bill3 = new Bill();

        NumberBinding total = Bindings.add(bill1.amountDueProperty().add(bill2.amountDueProperty()),
          bill3.amountDueProperty());
        total.addListener(new InvalidationListener() {

        @Override public void invalidated(Observable o) {
                System.out.println("The binding is now invalid.");
            }
        });

        // First call makes the binding invalid
        bill1.setAmountDue(200.00);

        // The binding is now invalid
        bill2.setAmountDue(100.00);
        bill3.setAmountDue(75.00);

        // Make the binding valid...
        System.out.println(total.getValue());

        // Make invalid... 
        bill3.setAmountDue(150.00);

        // Make valid...
        System.out.println(total.getValue());
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: Throw this code into an IDE and you'll find out really quickly why it isn't compiling. The usage of ```Bindings.add(...``` looks like it might be the culprit, but I'm not familiar with that class

Comment: With just the example code in a JavaFX application an empty box comes up asking to select class.  This made me think that it doesn't work because it's not extending the Application class, but that didn't seem to work either.  So really no error, it just stops because the base class is somehow invalid.